# How to iterrate over dataframe to shift subset of columns down

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use pd.iterrows over the rows of a dataframe and if the value in colA does not equal the value in colC, then shift colC and colD down one row. I thought the best way to achieve this was with iterrows but i cant get it to work.

df

```
     colA  colB colC colD
      A    foo    A   foo
      A    foo    B   no
      B    yes    B   no
      B    yes
```

desired result

```
     colA  colB  colC colD
      A    foo    A   foo
      A    foo               
      B    yes    B   no
      B    yes    B   no
```

I have tried: (returns an empty dataframe)

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.colA != row.colC:
    df = df.iloc[:,2:3].shift(1)
```

Any suggestions would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over row if you create virtual index for each group of columns (colA, colB) and (colC, colD). After that you can safely merge subsets on (colA, idx) and (colC, idx):

```
cols1 = ['colA', 'colB']  # first group of columns
cols2 = ['colC', 'colD']  # second group of columns
out = (pd.merge(df[cols1].assign(idx=lambda x: x.groupby(cols1[0]).cumcount()),
                df[cols2].assign(idx=lambda x: x.groupby(cols2[0]).cumcount()),
                left_on=[cols1[0], 'idx'], right_on=[cols2[0], 'idx'], how='outer')
         .drop(columns='idx').dropna(how='all', axis=0))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  colA colB colC colD
0    A  foo    A  foo
1    A  foo  NaN  NaN
2    B  yes    B   no
3    B  yes    B   no
```